Guide to implementing spring forget password and rest Password with dynamic URL sent to email
I want to implementing spring forget password and reset Password  with dynamic URL sent to email
Here is the code:
String baseUrl = createPasswordUrl.getUrl() + "/login/form";
            // Building URI with query parameters
            UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(baseUrl).queryParam("token", encryptAccessToken).queryParam("firstName", adminDetails.getFirstName()).queryParam("lastName", adminDetails.getLastName()).queryParam("schoolImage", fileStorageService.getSignedUrl(existingSchool.get().getMediaPath()));
            String generatedLink = builder.toUriString();

I tried:
String baseUrl = createPasswordUrl.getUrl() + "/login/form";
            // Building URI with query parameters
            UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(baseUrl).queryParam("token", encryptAccessToken).queryParam("firstName", adminDetails.getFirstName()).queryParam("lastName", adminDetails.getLastName()).queryParam("schoolImage", fileStorageService.getSignedUrl(existingSchool.get().getMediaPath()));
            String generatedLink = builder.toUriString();

above generatedLink is send to email but in browser it append all information token firstName,LastName
and schoolImage
url=http://localhost:8082/api/dev/login/staff/update/form?token=iJeUGVFo973jR8rO5a8CqYcUOYITEpS/j3FNnbuRRGMBnMJADsnyoQYEv26VXnYruY5RMasnwKx07+jCP0JevTJgWhOF1a/vKTSar5yQ4WZGAg6/b0M5o8bruyS6b0m/HNqD7uoiVtyCkZX1zdCuks5yDn9X49Zuvm7BU/tMTV7SZGqvcnXRFaUkm+0KuaOueGvnDaghOlnd8dEnKVa+Kw==&firistName="dddd"&lastName=vijay&schoolImage=shkjsks
but am expecting like that
http://localhost:8082/api/dev/login/staff/update/form/ASYCJXCRISCUGXCY4H3UI4DGCPYUJBNFMVWWC2LMWZ3GS2TBPFZGC2RRGEZTAQDHNVQWS3BOMNXW3JLGN5ZGGZOCWN2HO327MZQWG5DPOJPXMZLSNFTGSZLEYKYXI53PL5TGCY3UN5ZF63LFORUG6ZFENZXW4ZN2MZXXEY3FMRPXOZLBNNPXAYLTON3W64TEL5ZGK43FOTBA?auto=true
please give me solution
